# List of Pairs of Chars in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, char, tuples

Is there a function in Haskell where say if you supplied a Char, and a List of 13 Pairs of Chars (all different i.e. every letter of the alphabet was used once and only once) it would return you the Char which is paired with your inputted Char i.e. if I inputted the following:

pairedChar Q [(A,Z),(B,Y),(C,X),(D,W),(E,V),(F,U),(G,T),(H,S),(I,R),(J,Q),(K,P),(L,O),(M,N)]

I would like it to return J?

If there isn't a function like that I was thinking maybe of doing it with unzip to get a pair of lists but wasn't sure what to do with the lists after I get them?

Comment: You should not have to unzip, you can just go down (using the pattern match ((x,y):ss) this list as pairs and check if either member of the pair is an input if it is return the other one.

Comment: only remember, Char is `'s'`, so your code must look like `pairedChar 'Q' [('A','Z'),('B','Y'),...`

Comment: [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) is good at answering questions of the form "is there a function that does X"; just type your type signature into the search box. Also consider whether you really want a `Map`.

Answer (score 4):

The lookup function does this; not just for the kind of pairs you describe but for any list of two-element tuples. A list of such tuples is known as an association list, by the way.

It returns a Maybe,  because there might beono match.

```
lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b
lookup key assocs

looks up a key in an association list
```

Comment: It doesn't work the other way though? If I do it with A, B, C etc. i.e. the first char of the pair, it works fine but with Q it returns Nothing?

Comment: Ah,you want to match either element?  No, there is no standard library function which does precisely that. What would you want to return if the list were longer and ['Q','I'] appeared later in the list?

Answer (score 2):

This answer builds on `itsbruce`'s answer by still using `lookup`, but also first massaging the input list to include each pair twice, once for each ordering of elements.

Let's assume that your list is called `pairs`:

```
pairs :: [(Char, Char)]
pairs = [('A', 'Z'), ('B', 'Y'), ..., ('M', 'N')]
```

Then all you need to do is duplicate each pair and swap the elements:

```
import Data.Tuple (swap)

allPairs :: [(Char, Char)]
allPairs = pairs ++ map swap pairs

-- allPairs = [('A', 'Z') ... ('M', 'N'), ('Z', 'A'), ... ('N', 'M')]
```

... where `swap` is a function from `Data.Tuple` that takes the two elements of a tuple and swaps them.  It's defined like this:

```
swap :: (a, b) -> (b, a)
swap (x, y) = (y, x)
```

Now you can do a `lookup` on the `allPairs` list:

```
pairedChar :: Char -> Maybe Char
pairedChar c = lookup c allPairs
```

If you want each duplicate pair to be adjacent to each other in the list, then you can also write `allPairs` like this:

```
allPairs = do
    (x, y) <- pairs
    [(x, y), (y, x)]
```

Now it will contain this ordering:

```
allPairs = [('A', Z'), ('Z', 'A'), ('B', 'Y'), ('Y', 'B') ... ('M', 'N'), ('N', 'M')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just make a longer list.

```
alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRTSUVXYZ"

pairs = zip alphabet (reverse alphabet)

theOtherChar k = lookup k pairs --does the job for you now.
```